# Strange attribute overshadowing between classes in separate C# files

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 classes (which are drawing lines) in separate files. Each containing separate(?) public attribute with the same name but different value.

```
//ClassA.cs
public class ClassA: MonoBehaviour
{
   public Color lineColour = new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  //red
//(...)
}
```

```
//ClassB.cs
public class ClassB: MonoBehaviour
{
   public Color lineColour = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  //blue
   //(...)
}
```

For some reason when I access attribute `lineColour` in ClassB it gets value from ClassA, as if some between-files overshadowing happened:

```
// in ClassB.cs
  (...)
  lineRenderer.startColor = lineColour;
  lineRenderer.endColor = lineColour;
  (...)
// draws line in red color instead of blue
```

If I only change variable name in `ClassB` to something different than `lineColour`, everything works as intended.

Is this overshadowing normal behaviour? Or I must be doing some silly mistake?

Comment: "Is this overshadowing normal behaviour" Definitly not, however without knowing your *actual* code, it's impossible to guess what might be the issue here. In particular we need to know where `lineRenderer` comes from and how it relates to `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

Comment: There's no such thing as "between-files overshadowing". It probably has to do with both classes being derived from the same type somehow, which is the only obvious relation. Still, we'll need a more detailed snippet of the ClassB to confirm that.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't maybe just assign a different Color via the Inspector? Have in mind that the value in code for serialized fields is just the **default** value .. as soon as the component has been serialized with a value this value you see in the Inspector overrules any later change in code => I vote silly mistake :P  ... This said: I see no good reason to have two different types for this at all ... Just use the same class but assign two different colors via the Inspector... Might also want to look into `ScriptableObject` instead of having those settings in components

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the provided code snippets apart from the sub-optimal design. These classes should derive from a common base class exposing the common attributes.

Comment: If anyone interested, found the reason (see answer below). Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason: This "overshadowing" came from Inspector (thanks @derHugo for the hint!).

When using object of ClassB I did not even touch Inspector. I was changing colors programatically, so did not bother to check it.

The reason Inspector had some value being set was I copied whole Game Object (which contained Class A script) to create new Game Object for Class B. When copying objects, Inspector settings got copied as well, overruling anything I did in the code.